# Need to do a group by count of id and at the same time get the total of count without a group by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Need to do a group by count of id and at the same time get the total of count without a group by
This is so I can get the total count of the id and check the percentage of each group by category compared to the total count.

-- Its for an oracle sql script

Something like the following is what I currently have:

```
SELECT
    count(id) as unit_count,
    category
FROM sales
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY count(id) DESC;

SELECT
    count(id) as total_count
FROM sales
```

I am not sure how to combine the above two

The final result I am looking for is the following:

| category | count | percentage_of_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| televisions | 100 | 25% |
| mobile phones | 300 | 75% |

Comment: You can easily group by anything with subquery in the `from` (or using CTE). Just calculate what you need and `select` anything you need from this calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are calculated after aggregates. This means that `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()` will total up the counts across the entire result set...

```
SELECT
    category,
    count(id) as unit_count,
    COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS percentage_of_all_units
FROM sales
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY count(id) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your table nor data, so here's example based on Scott's sample schema.

Number of rows in `emp` table:

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14
```

Number of employees per job:

```
SQL> select job,
  2    count(*) cnt
  3  from emp
  4  group by job
  5  order by cnt desc;

JOB              CNT
--------- ----------
CLERK              4
SALESMAN           4
MANAGER            3
ANALYST            2
PRESIDENT          1
```

Combined (i.e. what you're asking):

```
SQL> select job,
  2    count(*) cnt,
  3    round((count(*) / (select count(*) from emp) * 100), 0) pct
  4  from emp
  5  group by job
  6  order by cnt desc;

JOB              CNT        PCT
--------- ---------- ----------
CLERK              4         29
SALESMAN           4         29
MANAGER            3         21
ANALYST            2         14
PRESIDENT          1          7

SQL>
```

Alternatively, as @Mat suggested, line#3 might be

```
round((count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () * 100), 0) pct
```

---

Applied to your case:

```
select category,
  count(*) as unit_count,
  round((count(*) / (select count(*) from sales) * 100), 0) percentage_of_total,
  --
  round((count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () * 100), 0) percentage_of_total_2
from sales
group by category
order by unit_count desc;
```

Comment: Or, just use a window function instead of a sub-query?

Comment: Which one do you have on mind, @Mat? I guess it is not `count(*) over()` (in my example it'll return 5 because of GROUP BY clause). Hm?

Comment: `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()`; the count is calculated first as it's an aggregate, then the sum is calculated after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample table as per the scenario mentioned:

```
create table sales(id number(3),
category    varchar2(20))
/

insert all
into sales values('01','televisions')
into sales values('02','televisions')
into sales values('03','televisions')
into sales values('04','televisions')
into sales values('05','televisions')
into sales values('06','televisions')
into sales values('07','mobile phones')
into sales values('08','televisions')
into sales values('09','mobile phones')
into sales values('10','mobile phones')
into sales values('11','televisions')
into sales values('12','televisions')
select * from dual;
/
select * from sales;
/
-- Required Query --
select category,count(*) count,
(count(*) / (select count(*) from sales) * 100)||'%' percentage_of_total
from sales
group by category;
```